# I can't find the Screen Options menu when editing blog posts

Tags: screen-options

I am trying to change the author of a blog post but can't find the Screen Options menu when editing a blog post.  Can you help?  I've included a screen shot.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you have more than 1 user, you should see an author dropdown on the right under status and visibility.  Do you have more than 1 user?

[image]

Comment: Ah.  Thanks.  I just invited the other user.  So when they confirm, I assume I'll see the author box?  Many thanks!

Comment: Yes, it will show up.  I have tested this but you could always setup a test user to see for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the author of an existing post in your WordPress website from your **Dashboard**, under **Posts**. Click on **Quick Edit** for the post whose author you would like to change and find the **Author** drop-down. From the drop-down menu choose the new author and then click the **Update** button to save the change.
[image]